# ParseInt Processing

Tags: parsing, processing

Can someone help me to understand why if my val value is a `"0"` `Integer.parseInt(val)` returns me `NumberFormatException` and if i write `Integer.parseInt("0")` it works correctly...

There's a way easier to work directly with the int value read from Serial?

```
 void draw(){
     i=0;
     byte[] str = new byte[5];

     if ( myPort.available() > 0) 
     {  
        myPort.readBytesUntil(10, inBuffer);
        if(inBuffer==null){
            //...
        }
        else
        {
            while(inBuffer[i]!=13){
                str[i]=inBuffer[i];
                println((int)str[i]);
                i++;
            }
            String val = new String(str);
            i = Integer.parseInt(val);
            println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Processing `port.readBytesUntil(ch, buffer)` reads all characters from `port` until encounter character equal to `ch`. 
In Windows line separator is composed from 2 characters `(0d,0a)` or `(13,10)`.

So if you write to serial `"23"`, next newline, next `"45"`, etc., the `buffer` will look like this:

```
char[] buffer : '2', '3', '0x0d', '0x0a', '4', '5', '0x0d', '0x0a', ...
```

So when you `readBytesUntil(10, ...)` it read 3 characters: `'2', '3', '0x0d'`.

Consider such example:

```
char[] c = {'2', '3', 13};
String str = new String(c);
System.out.println(str);                // you will see "23"
System.out.println(str.length());       // lenght will be 3
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str.trim()));   // will be OK
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str));  // will throw NumberFormatException
```

So try to convert your buffer to String and `trim()` this string.

== EDIT ==

---

Processing gives you some convenience methods such as:

```
String str = port.readStringUntil(10);
str = str.trim();
```

Comment: OHHHH! Thanks I didn't know that  a function like trim() exists, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score -1):

Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem? Use hardcoded values and keep it as simple as possible, like this:

```
void setup(){
  String val = "0";
  int i = Integer.parseInt(val);
  println(i);
}
```

Print out the value of val before you try parsing it. I would bet it's not the value you think it is.

Comment: This is not an answer and should be a comment.

Comment: @IngoBürk I disagree. The answer was to print out the value of the String before parsing it, and that'll work 90% of the time this error occurs.

Comment: No, your post asks the OP to print out before parsing because you suspect the value is different. It's suspicion and asking for feedback, not answering the question.